# Webpack and Typescript compiling multi-directory project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, module

I'm here once again to ask for some help, this time regarding webpack and typescript. I've had a lot of problems with `exports is not defined`, it seems that the browser can't understand typescript import/export, so people suggested me to use webpack.

I'm trying to understand how they work togheter, and more specifically, in a project divided into different folders and sub-folders.

Let's assume this is my project structure

```
- myProject/
 - src/
  - server.ts
  - game/
    - Game.ts
    - Player.ts
  - static/
    - js/
     - game.ts
 - build/

  // build use same structure of src/
```

In my first attempt, I used **Gulp** to compile TS to JS, and it worked the way I wanted, it took the structure of **src/** and compiled everything mirror-like in the **build/** folder.

Minus ofcourse the exports problem, which obviously didn't allow me to split my project and import various classes I need.

So I gave a try to webpack, using this configuration

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
         server: "./src/server.ts",
         game: "./src/static/js/game.ts",
         gameClasses: ["./src/game/Game.ts", "./src/game/Player.ts"]

        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
            filename: "[name].js"
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: [
            "node_modules",
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./")
        ],
            // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as a resolvable extension.
            extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                // all files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
            ]
        }
    }
```

This one is a very basic configuration I copied from the documentation, the only change I made is tell the config about **node_modules** folder and multiple entry points, but it seems things are not working properly, when I try to compile I get tons of yellow/red errors about modules :

```
 Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
     server.js  1.96 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  server
gameClasses.js   3.5 kB       1  [emitted]         gameClasses
       game.js  3.38 kB       2  [emitted]         game
   [4] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
  [45] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
  [74] ./src/game/Game.ts 567 bytes {1} {2} [built]
 [152] ./src/server.ts 828 bytes {0} [built]
 [225] ./node_modules/express/lib 160 bytes {0} [built]
 [341] ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$ 404 bytes {0} [built]
 [365] ./node_modules/socket.io/lib 160 bytes {0} [built]
 [366] ./src/static/js/game.ts 235 bytes {2} [built]
 [367] multi ./src/game/Game.ts ./src/game/Player.ts 40 bytes {1} [built]
 [368] ./src/game/Player.ts 199 bytes {1} [built]
    + 359 hidden modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
108:11-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
81:13-25 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 35:21-42
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/Validation.js 10:22-47
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_linux_51.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_linux_48.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_linux_47.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_linux_46.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_48.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_51.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_47.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_46.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_win32_48.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/uws/uws_win32_51.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/uws ^\.\/uws_.*$
 @ ./node_modules/uws/uws.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/lib/engine.io.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 14:17-30
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/etag'
 @ ./node_modules/etag/index.js 22:12-25
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/express/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/mime'
 @ ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 2:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/send'
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js 23:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/socket.io/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js 7:11-24 9:13-26
 @ ./src/server.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/k3nzie/projects/tsGame/node_modules/express/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 18:11-25
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./src/server.ts
```

**little edit:** holy moly! server.js is 2MB, quite heavy... I wonder why...

For reference, here are the imports in my **server.ts**

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let app = express();
let server = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

and in my **game.js** there is class import

```
import { Game } from "./../../game/Game";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is this the correct approach to achieve what I want (like the output structure from Gulp)?

Comment: If you take the server.ts entry point out do you still get any errors? If not, are you happy with the state of your game/gameClasses output bundles in relation to browser-based deployment?

Comment: @Rhys Yes, if I take server.js as the only entry point I get the same errors...